# Error CrashLoopBackOff Heapster with Statsd Sink Configuration

Tags: kubernetes, datadog, heapster

I got error with the latest heapster version: `v1.5.1`. I've described in detail in this github issue link: https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/issues/1969

The error message:

```
Container   Timestamp   Message
heapster    Mar 2, 2018, 11:03:20 AM    /go/src/k8s.io/heapster/metrics/heapster.go:89 +0x458
heapster    Mar 2, 2018, 11:03:20 AM    main.main()
heapster    Mar 2, 2018, 11:03:20 AM    /go/src/k8s.io/heapster/metrics/heapster.go:194 +0x8d
heapster    Mar 2, 2018, 11:03:20 AM    main.createAndInitSinksOrDie(0xc42028f3b0, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x4a817c800, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc420154740, 0x0, ...)
heapster    Mar 2, 2018, 11:03:20 AM    /go/src/k8s.io/heapster/metrics/sinks/factory.go:90 +0x563
heapster    Mar 2, 2018, 11:03:20 AM    k8s.io/heapster/metrics/sinks.(*SinkFactory).BuildAll(0xc4205e1cd8, 0xc42028f3b0, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7fb87afb8400, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
heapster    Mar 2, 2018, 11:03:20 AM    goroutine 1 [running]:
heapster    Mar 2, 2018, 11:03:20 AM    
heapster    Mar 2, 2018, 11:03:20 AM    [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x28 pc=0x15f77a3]
heapster    Mar 2, 2018, 11:03:20 AM    panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
heapster    Mar 2, 2018, 11:03:20 AM    I0302 04:03:20.258025 1 configs.go:62] Using kubelet port 10255
heapster    Mar 2, 2018, 11:03:20 AM    I0302 04:03:20.258013 1 configs.go:61] Using Kubernetes client with master "https://kubernetes.default" and version v1
heapster    Mar 2, 2018, 11:03:20 AM    I0302 04:03:20.257857 1 heapster.go:79] Heapster version v1.5.1
heapster    Mar 2, 2018, 11:03:20 AM    I0302 04:03:20.257820 1 heapster.go:78] /heapster --source=kubernetes:https://kubernetes.default --sink="statsd:udp://dd-agent-service.default:8125"
```

Anybody knows how to solve it? Perhaps someone who already successfully integrated the heapster to datadog statsd agent in Kubernetes?

Thanks before

Comment: Could you briefly describe your k8s cluster? have you tried with a previous version of heapster?

Comment: hi @whites11 the problem is resolved. In the github issue conversation, it is mentioned that the problem is caused by misconfiguration on putting double quote in heapster sink argument.